# Testing if a client certificat is installed in the client browser

Tags: php, ssl, certificate

I was wondering if any of you know if it is possible in javascript or php to test if a client has a specific client certificate installed in the browser.

The thing is that we have a server certificate installed but to be recognized by the clients, they need 2 client certificates that make them recognize the authority of the issuer of our server certificate. We would like to test the browser for these 2 certificates, if there are not there, we want to propose the client to download them before to enter in https mode...

Anybody can help? Please detail your answer if you know one.

Comment: You should only need to test for one certificate on the client side, the root certificate.

Comment: yes, the thing is that our new server certificate is depending from an authority that is new and not known by all browsers. We need browser like firefox to download the new root CA so they can recognize our server certificate. But I dont know how to test if a browser already have the root CA or if it need to download it. As soon as you connect on https to our server, you get that our server certificate is not trustable because the authority is not known. Unless you install the client certificat for the root CA.

Comment: That is not what 'client certificate' means. You want to know if a particular root certificate is trusted by the client. That's different.

Comment: Yes, I think its call like that, Im not expert in this just discovering. I just know that I have 2 certificates that my clients browser should install if they want to be able to recognize my server certificat. I want to offer them the option to do that before going in https if only they still need it...

Comment: A client certificate is a certificate that identifies the client. it is unusual to use a client certificate in normal secure web browsing. normally its used in a higher security situation. What you are talking about is the ROOT CA.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it client side by using javascript to request a known file from a secured (https) source. if the request fails then it means the client refused to accept your certificate (or another network error) at this point you could popup a message to ask the user to install the root certificate with a link to the root certificate.

This must be done from a non secure page. otherwise the user may refuse your certificate and never load the page to start with and therefore your javascript never runs

It can't be done in PHP because php (which is server side) cannot determine whether the client browser has a particular root ca installed

I however would not do this. get a proper certificate instead.

You appear to have insufficient understanding of how SSL works in general. I suggest spending some time understanding how SSL works and how certificates are used.

DC

to learn about sending and receiving http responses with javascript read this page..

http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_http.asp

It can be used to send and receive any text data, not just xml. It is real easy to implement but you must be aware of browser version issues.

DC

Comment: I confirm I have a bad knowledge in SSL works. There are so many technologies on the internet you can't know and be specialised on everything that why I asked for help.
Since the time, we have decided  as a solution, to put a non https page on our web site, explaining that there is a need to install new certificates before proceeding next secure page. Its not very nice but it is the only thing we found to solve our problem...
About your solution, I wonder how you request a file via javascript.. is there any download function? you use document.location ? Question is just for informal purpose.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a link to using javascript to load a file from the server. this is the basis for most ajax functionality

Answer (score 0):

what about a warning message that will be hidden by a javascript which will be loaded from your https site.

in the warning message you can link the windows update site or wherever the updated root certifcates can be downloaded to their browser.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language. If you really want to test this then you need to do it with JavaScript and then send back an AJAX request to PHP.

But I think there is another solution to your problem. Normally when a CA change their name etc. they have usually new "Intermediate Certificates" you can use. (If you have an apache httpd server then you can search for "ca bundle" on their website as well.) With this bundle you can send the new CA certificate along with your certificate.

Answer (score -1):

Forcing your users to download and install a homegrown CA certificate is ugly and hateful. Instead, show them the love and pay the $30 US to get an SSL certificate signed by a reputable, already trusted, CA.

Comment: Well... We are using a trusted certificat, but the company recently change their CA and we have already pay them for this server certificate so we would like to use it. Just like they have a new ROOT CA authority certificate, browsers not up to date, dont know them. We all know that people dont update their browser often... and safari,firefox dont work via windows update... So we trying to find a solution. But for sure, we are really not happy of this change and so of our SSL Certificate provider. Too bad, it was correct price and recognized by all browser at the start...

Comment: Our server certificat is a wildcart certificat and is much more then 30$ :)

Comment: Still I agree with you, this is a shit procedure to make people download and install ROOT CA authority certificat... This should not happen. We are not lucky.

Comment: Only Internet explorer seems to recognize it and i am not even sure.

Comment: Therefor the problem still. It is curious that nothing seems to have been done to be able to test the list of installed certificat from a client browser without being already in ssl... Interesting problem isnt it ?

Comment: I don't think there is a neat Javascript solution. Each platform, Windows, Firefox, Java, Safari, Opera, etc. does it differently, so it is a tough problem. Go with a CA common to all those platforms.

Comment: If they changed their root CA and browsers don't recognise it then request a refund. they broke the certificate not you. then go to a reputable company and get a new certificate. All other options are prone to serious issues and make you look like a shonky business

Comment: Actually, I think I know the CA (IPS Servidores) and their roots expired. I don't know if they pointed this fact out to their customers, but there is at least a small element of caveat emptor since this fact was detectable just by examining the roots in question.